# RPi3: Bluetooth BlueZ working locally but not in Docker

Tags: c#, docker, bluetooth, azure-iot-edge

i'm working on HashtagChris **bluetooth** library for C# (https://github.com/hashtagchris/DotNet-BlueZ). The scan sample is working on my **raspberry Pi** perfectly, but not in a Docker container. I can detect the Bluetooth chip with adapter hci0 as seen on below screenshot (so I know I have enough privilege for the container to access the chip), but the cs program doesn't seem to find it when executing (i'm running the app through a **dockerfile**, in an **Azure IoT Edge** context).
[Execution logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IroIf.png)

Even when I run GetAdaptersAsync() to find all available adapters, with another error:
[Execution logs 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GlQM.png)

uname -a:
[System info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qr7t.png)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
USER root

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime-stretch-slim-arm32v7
WORKDIR /app
USER root

RUN apt update -y && \
    apt install -y build-essential systemd bluez bluez-tools bluez-hcidump     \
    bluez-obexd libbluetooth3 libglib2.0-dev libboost-all-dev     libbluetooth-dev \
    rfkill dbus-x11 nano pciutils util-linux libcap-dev \
    pulseaudio-module-bluetooth git bc libusb-dev libdbus-1-dev libudev-    dev \
    libical-dev libreadline-dev autoconf libncurses5-dev wget \
    pulseaudio-module-bluetooth

RUN cd ~ && \
    wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/json-c_releases/releases/json-c-    0.13.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvf json-c-0.13.tar.gz && \
    cd json-c-0.13/ && \
    ./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static && \
    make -j8 && \
    make install -j8 && \
    rm -rf json-c-0.13.tar.gz json-c-0.13

RUN cd ~ && \
    wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/ell/ell-0.6.tar.xz     && \
    tar -xvf ell-0.6.tar.xz && \
    cd ell-0.6/ && \
    ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
    make -j2 && \
    make install -j2 && \
    rm -rf ell-0.6.tar.xz ell-0.6

RUN cd ~ && \
    wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.50.tar.xz && \
    tar -xvf bluez-5.50.tar.xz && \
    cd bluez-5.50/ && \
    ./configure --enable-mesh --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --    sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var && \
    make -j2 && \
    make install -j2 && \
    rm -rf bluez-5.50.tar.xz bluez-5.50/ && \
    cp /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd-    543.orig && \
    ln -sf /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

COPY --from=build-env /app/out ./
COPY --from=build-env /app/launch.sh ./

RUN chmod 777 ./launch.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "./launch.sh"]
```

Launch script:

```
#!/bin/bash

YELLOW="\e[0;93m"
NC="\e[0m"

echo -e "$YELLOW\n\n Launching Script...$NC"

export DISPLAY=:0.0

echo -e "$YELLOW Starting DBus Service...$NC"
service dbus start; sleep 1; echo -e '\n';

echo -e "$YELLOW Starting Bluetooth Service...$NC"
service bluetooth start
bluetoothd -v

echo -e "$YELLOW HCIConfig: Activating hci0...$NC"
hciconfig hci0 up
hciconfig hci0 piscan
hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1
hciconfig -a
#rfcomm watch hci0

echo -e "$YELLOW rfkill list$NC"
rfkill list

echo -e "$YELLOW hcitool dev$NC"
hcitool dev

echo -e "$YELLOW ls /sys/class/bluetooth$NC"
ls /sys/class/bluetooth

echo -e "$YELLOW journalctl -xb | grep blue$NC"
journalctl -xb | grep blue

echo -e "$YELLOW Launching Main Function$NC"
dotnet BluetoothModule.dll

echo -e "$YELLOW Terminating Script...\n\n$NC"
```

[JSON Deployment template, mounts and binds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vETl.png)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Trying to run that script just produces `: command not found?PNG`.  It looks like you might have attached an image of some sort instead of the actual script you ran?  Can you replace these links with the actual text of the commands you're running and the relevant source code, and the actual text of the errors you're getting?

Comment: Here you go. Couldn't format logs because I don't have them anymore except in screenshots

Comment: Docker images typically don't run a display daemon or an init system (and especially not systemd) and have very restricted access to the host's hardware devices.  This seems like a setup you want to run directly on the host system and not isolated inside a container.

Comment: Forgot to add the json deployment with mounts and binds. See last hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i've managed to make it, just by manually stopping/starting bluetoothd just before starting dotnet module. If anyone has an explanation, I would be grateful, thanks!
[Restarting bluetoothd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShnaT.png)